# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'

Tags: android, gradle, android-youtube-api, android-multidex

I am getting an ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex' Error when I try to build an application using the YouTubeData API. I have researched several other threads that cover this error and the conclusion that I have come to is that I have libraries in my build file that are creating a duplicated reference to build files. I know that the file triggering the error is:

> 'com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonErrorContainer.class'

but how do I exclude the reference from the build file with out removing the entire library?

This is my build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.hannalupi.fitnessblenderapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev136-1.20.0'

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonErrorContainer.class
```

I am new to Android, any direction you can point me in would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An update for folks having a similar error - As a last resort I deleted the project file that I was working in from my desktop and cloned a fresh copy from GitHub. Importing and running the fresh copy gave me no errors!!